# RegEx for a specific string pattern

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

Using C#, I will be handling character arrays of info, looking for the following pattern:

a pipe (0x7C), 2 to 7 pairs of characters, followed by another pipe (0x7C).

Stated another way:

|1122[33][44][55][66][77]|

The character pairs consist of characters whose range is from 33-124 decimal ( '!' to '|').

Pairs 3 through 7 are optional, but occur in order, if they occur, so you could have

```
    |1122| <---shortest
    |112233|
    |11223344|
    |1122334455|
    |112233445566|
    |11223344556677| <---longest
```

I want to 1) find out if this pattern exists in the character array, 2) extract the individual pairs. These tasks can be separate. I *think* the best approach to this would be a RegEx, but so far I haven't been able to dream-up an expression to get the job done.

Is a RegEx the way to go and what would a solution for the RegEx itself be?

Is there a better way?

Chuck

Comment: So, I've kept working at it and came up with |[!-|]{2,7}| for a regex. The question remains how to do this AND extract the minimum 2 pairs and optional remaining 5 pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly the correct pattern would be:

```
\|([!-|]{2}){2,7}\|
```

Or to capture each set

```
\|([!-|]{2})([!-|]{2})([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?([!-|]{2})?\|
```

Not sure if the range will work directly like that or not, so you may need to do `[A-Za-Z!@#$......]` if the simplified range doesn't work

Also, I think you don't want to include pipe(`|`) in the range as it could mess up the rest so `[!-{]` might be better

Comment: Ben, thank-you for a quick and elegant response. I just spent a few minutes playing with this expression in Expresso and it works as desired.

RegExs always look so logical once solved.